# SMD 5050 LED current draw calculation

Tags: led, led-strip

I am trying to calculate max current draw for SMD 5050 LED strip.
Datasheet says that 1 channel draws 20mA. 
So I do the calculations: 20mA * 300leds * 3channels = 18A

I already have the same strip with power supply (12V 5A) and it is working fine when all channels are high (white). 
If it would be 18A, wouldn't it burn? I don't understand what am I doing wrong in the calculations. :(
Could anyone help please?

LED Datasheet: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://e-radionica.com/productdata/RGB5050LED.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj8yvCTr87oAhXhoosKHRDqCvAQFjALegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw3B5Ja9lwTl9we5GdXwR4Gp

Strip Datasheet: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.iled.com/class/INNOVAEditor/assets/gallery2/5100-5105.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjC163XwM7oAhWys4sKHS7FDw8QFjALegQIBBAC&usg=AOvVaw3dRnzlhi1q8HrHmk2auw3g

Comment: You forgot that "max" is "max".

Comment: You haven't provided links for the datasheets you are working from. "*1 channel draws 20mA*" is more likely "one LED draws 20 mA".  "*I already have a strip with power supply (12V 5A) and it is working fine.*" We don't know how many LEDs are on that strip so that sentence doesn't help. Hit the edit link below your question and add in the missing information.

Comment: Right, we've got the LED datasheet. What about the "strip" datasheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. From the [datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.iled.com/class/INNOVAEditor/assets/gallery2/5100-5105.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjC163XwM7oAhWys4sKHS7FDw8QFjALegQIBBAC&usg=AOvVaw3dRnzlhi1q8HrHmk2auw3g) it is clear that the LEDs are wired with three in series.*

What you have missed is that each 20 mA powers three LEDs in series. This is the most efficient arrangement for a 12 V supply and little power is lost in the series resistors.

Re-running your calculation we get:

$$ I = \frac {20 \ \text {mA} \times 300 \ LEDs \times 3 \ \text {channels}} {3 \ \text {LEDs / string}} = 6 \ \text A $$

---

From the comments:

> Calculations say that max current is 6A, but my power supply is 5A. When I turn the color to white, everything is fine. But why?

1. Measure the actual current being drawn. Remember to put your ammeter **in series** with the load - not directly across the supply.
2. The PSU won't just stop at 5.001 A. Typically the voltage will start to collapse to keep the load to a safe value. It depends on the type of PSU.
3. The PSU rating may be conservative.
4. The PSU might be running hot and it will die prematurely.

Comment: Thank you for your response! There is only 1 thing I don't get right now. Calculations say that max current is 6A, but my power supply is 5A. When I turn the color to white, everything is fine. But why?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Okay, this is a very good answer, now it's clear for me, thank youuu! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is drawing less than the paper 6 amps for several reasons.

- voltage drop down the long strip.  Those internal pathways are PCB traces, not superconductors.
- cheap items of foreign manufacture are not running 100% to spec.
- actually, LED strips are sized to work safely on 14 volts, i.e. Automobile battery float voltage.  So you are not running them at full spec.